# PHP <= malfunctions when first number is less

Tags: php, mysqli, comparison-operators

I have the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reward_table WHERE _cost <= '$_points' ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $_title[] = $row_s['_title'];
    $_cost[] = $row_s['_cost'];
    $_id[] = $row_s['ID'];
}
```

When `_cost` is, for example, set at 8792, and `$_points` is 8793  then the particular reward shows. When `_cost` is updated to 8794 then it disappears, which is great - works. However...

When `_cost` is set to 10000, it also shows? But, when I change `_cost` to 9000 it disappears as it should. I'm so confused - have I coded something wrong..? It appears like the code will only work if the starting digit of `_cost` is higher or the same as the starting digit of `$_points`.

Your help is much appreciated and will stop me going totally insane!

Comment: What's the table definition? Is `_cost` a text field rather than numeric perhaps?

Comment: Try `CAST(_cost AS UNSIGNED) <= $_points`. It sounds like you're doing a string comparison, in which case `'10000' < '2'`

Comment: You're both right. As soon as I changed the row to INT it started working. Always a simple fix! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix - my table has _cost as text, rather than integer.
All works fine no need to change code. Fix was table-side.